# Why Windows toggles off laptop with new battery while Linux runs just fine

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, power

For most of what I do I (have to) use Windows 10. I got a new battery for a MSI GT70. With the new battery fully charged I can boot the machine to Windows, attempt a login, but before the desktop is shown, it just toggles off. With that I mean it is not a clean shut down. It also makes this strange "pock" noise. Maybe coming from the speakers or so. (It does not make that sound when the machine is turned off by holding the power button for 5 seconds.)

Then, with the same battery state, I can run Linux just fine. For hours, because the battery was fully charged.

Windows does recognize the battery to be fully charged. I even let Windows charge it from 2% to 100%. I got to the 2% battery state by letting Ubuntu drain it.

All the behavior described above only happens when the AC adapter is disconnected. Otherwise, Windows runs just fine.

I already uninstalled the battery drivers from Windows numerous times, with battery still in the machine, with the battery removed.

What in Windows can cause this immediate toggle off as soon as I login to Windows? The version I am using is Windows 10 1809.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Windows is using the machine in a more demanding way than Linux, for example it is more graphically demanding while also using the hard drive and other things.

As a result it would be drawing more power from the battery and if the battery is old, as in has been left on the shelf for an extended period, or defective it might not be able to supply enough current during the times when Windows is demanding it.

The fact that you have a gaming laptop could mean that you have both an integrated Intel graphics card and a more powerful Nvidia graphics card. If Linux is not set up to drive the Nvidia card then it could not be being turned on and you are running on only the lower power Intel graphics. When Windows boots it may power up the Nvidia card to set it up before putting it to sleep. The extra power drain could be overloading your battery and causing it to "brown-out" and your system to shut down.

Depending on where you got the battery from I would look at returning or replacing it.

Comment: This is conceivable, but hugely unlikely if Linux can run fine for hours. Linux power management/battery lifr is generally WORSE then Windows because vendors dont optimise for it.

Comment: @davidgo While I would agree for the large majority of devices there are times where having proper manufacturer supplied drivers can cause larger power draw. The GT70 is a "gaming" laptop and so it could be that the sudden power down is while enabling an Nvidia graphics card which will draw a lot more power than an integrated graphics card. It could well be that in Linux the Nvidia card is never used.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the answer. I did however ran a game via Steam in Ubuntu. But it was not so graphically demanding. It did recognize the presence of the GTX980m. Whether it used it, I do not know. 
@ davidgo I read that to. 
I've reinstalled Windows 10 1804, and it stays on longer now. It drains to 60% before it browns out. 
When at 100% charge, and I open a CPU and GPU intensive application, known to talk to the GPU using CUDA, it turns of immediately.
Oh darn.... This is already the 6th battery for this machine with this behavior... It seems no good batteries our available anymore.

Comment: If it's shutting down even before login, Windows shouldn't really be doing anything demanding at that point.

Comment: @fixer1234 unless you've disabled it Windows will start preloading the primary user profile for faster login and setting up updates. That could cause any number of things to happen, I've occasionally had Netflix or similar running and playing video before logging in as Windows already loaded up the browser where I left off... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-preloading-profile-of-the-last-user/378d2b7c-8d65-4fcb-8d07-1d8738f5ee7e

Comment: If it was running in the previous session, or more likely a subset of what was running in the previous session, there shouldn't be power demands so high that they would pop thermal breakers or drop the voltage to brownout levels within seconds when running on a fully charged battery. The symptoms don't sound consistent with a power demand issue. If the problem was a series of crap 3rd-party batteries, they wouldn't work in Linux, either.  It sounds more like an inability of Windows to properly deal with the battery (like maybe a driver issue).  But that's just an opinion.